# DPDK rte_eth_tx_burst() reliability

Tags: dpdk

According to the DPDK [documentation](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a83e56cabbd31637efd648e3fc010392b), the `rte_eth_tx_burst()` function takes a batch of packets, and returns the number of packets that have been actually stored in transmit descriptors of the transmit ring.

Assuming that the packets are sent exactly in the same order as they are inserted in the `tx_pkts` array parameter, it is possible to call the function iteratively until all the packets are sent. Here a sample code taken from one of the examples:

```
sent = 0;
do {
    n_pkts = rte_eth_tx_burst(portid, 0, &tx_pkts_burst[sent], n_mbufs - sent);
    sent += n_pkts;
} while (sent < n_mbufs);
```

However, using the above code, I see that, sometimes, the amount of packets that the function says are sent, are not really sent.

I am accumulating the return value of `rte_eth_tx_burst()` in a variable and, at the end of the job, the value of the accumulator is greater than the value of  `opackets`  in the device `eth_stats`.
I see the same number of transmitted packets in `eth_stats`, `eth_xstats` and on the other side of the cable, and this number is less than the sum of the values returned by `rte_eth_tx_burst()`.

So, my question is: in what case the `rte_eth_tx_burst()` function returns a value that does not correspond to the real number of transmitted packets?

According to the documentation, the function is returning only the number of packets that have been successfully inserted in the ring, so I assumed the return value was reliable.

My testbed:
NIC: Intel 82599ES
DPDK driver: igb_uio
DPDK version: 18.05
Traffic: UDP packets, sized 174B, with IP and UDP checksum offload

**Edit 1**

My test is the following:
the sender sends 32 messages with different IDs, then for each ACK received, a new message with the same ID of the ack-ed packet is sent again. The test ends when every ID has been sent and ack-ed N times (N=36864). 
As described above, at some point one packet is not sent, so all the IDs complete the cycle, except one. This is what I see as output:

```
ID - #sent
 0 - 36864
 1 - 36864
 2 - 36864
 3 - 36864
 4 - 8151
 5 - 36864
 6 - 36864
 7 - 36864
 ....
```

At the end of the test, the accumulator variable with the number of packets sent is greater than the stats and the difference is 1. So, it looks like the `rte_eth_tx_burst` function failed to send that one packet that is not acknowledged.

**Edit 2**

It can be relevant that the value "n_mbufs" is not necessarily constant, since the packets are read as a burst from a ring.

Comment: What’s the difference between the stats and the sum?

Comment: The difference in my case is 1. I updated the question with a description of the test.

Comment: Is it possible that a malformed packet is added to the transmit ring but not sent in the end (and not counted in the stats)?

Comment: Looks like an off by one error ;) Do you compare stats at the start? Did you check `oerrors` in stats? Sorry, without the source code it's just guessing...

Comment: `ierrors`, `oerrors`, `rx_nombuf`, `imissed` are all zero at the end of the test.
But I see `mac_remote_errors: 2` and `rx_l3_l4_xsum_error: 160388692`. Not sure it this helps. I am sure that the one packet has not been transmitted, because I also have a counter in the switch at the other side of the cable. Moreover,  the test for that ID is stuck.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.The `mac_remote_errors` maps to `MRFC` register (Number of faults in the remote MAC). It's not quite clear what NIC does when there is a remote error, maybe that is the source of the missing packet. The `rx_l3_l4_xsum_error ` IMO is a known issue, the counter gets increased when there is no UDP checksum.

Comment: Is program exit immediately after finish send？ If so, this may cause some packet not send. I send packets in the same way, only encounter error packet and exit too soon  may cause receive number not equals to send number.

Comment: dpdk API rte_tx_burst returns back successfully enqueued packet for transmission (note this is not actual transmission). The `get_stats` or dpdk-procinfo option `stats` only returns the PMD accounted stats. If one needs to get HW stats (if supported by NIC) `get_xstats` or dpdk-procinfo option `xstats` is the option. I do agree mission 1 packet is indeed an issue, can you share the details of your NIC, firmware, and HW offloads enabled if any?

Comment: are there any updates?